# How can i extract Json data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json result that is returned from my controller to a react javascript as follows, its a keyvalue pair and i want to display them on a antd grid.

```
      result.items
       
         0  key        {id:'123', name:'Bob'}
            value      '8987'

        1   key        {id:'428', name:'Karen'}
            value      '3258'
```

How can i extract these values independently ?

I have tried

```
JSON.parse(result.items.key);
```

but it says key is undefined

Comment: Looks like a bad copy and paste of an _array_?! `result.items[0].key`…?!

Comment: its in react so i dont have an index

Comment: I don't understand what that means, and you'll probably want to loop over the array to do something with each item anyway, instead of accessing one index directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your explanation, I think your JSON is looks something like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": { "id": "123", "name": "Bob" },
        "value": "8987"
      },
      {
        "key": { "id": "428", "name": "Karen" },
        "value": "3258"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you wanna extract the data independently you can use forEach in javascript. Let's assume u put your JSON in a variable called result, this is how you can extract the JSON datas:

```
result.result.items.forEach(item => {
  const { id, name } = item.key;
  const value = item.value;

  console.log(`ID: ${id}, Name: ${name}, Value: ${value}`);
});
```

Here im using variable desctructuring so we will get the id and name from the item.key directly without any extra code